# SQLite connectionstring where to writte it in .Net 6 Console App VisualStudio 2022

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0

I am totaly new with databases but this project needs one otherwise it wont work. So i need a SQLite Database. I installed ever NuGet needed and implemented my Database table with the rows and connected the Database with my project.

This is my class

```cs
   public class DatenbankDaten
   {
      public string zsw_id { get; set; }
      public int personio_id { get; set; }
      public string von { get; set; }
      public string bis { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the Code

```cs
private static string LoadConnectionString( string id = "Default")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
    }

    public void SaveIds ( DatenbankDaten daten)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Execute("insert into Ids (zsw_id,personio_id,von,bis) values (@zsw_id, @personio_id, @von, @bis", daten);
        }
    }
```

And i get a `NullReference exception` back.. I mean i understand it because i dont have written the connectionstring where it belongs too. At the moment the connectionstring is in my .csproj

```xml
      <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="zausinger.db">
            <connectionStrings>
                <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=.\zausinger.db;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
            </connectionStrings>
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
      </ItemGroup>

> and these are my PackageReferences

 

     <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.115.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.8.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="Telegram.Bot" Version="17.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup>    

if someone could help a newbie i would i appriciate it.
```

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. There's no `app.config` or `ConnectionManager`. Settings are loaded through the configuration middleware

Comment: take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration for how to read configuration values in .net 6

Comment: also... Execute is a method of a DbCommand not a DbConnection. Do have an extension method for that...if so there yould also be a problem in that method

Comment: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in .NET (Core) 6 is a compatibility library. It's only needed when migrating legacy .NET Framework code to .NET Core. It shouldn't be used in new project. Besides, precisely because .NET 6 doesn't use `app.config`, it won't rename it during deployment or even include it. You'll have to manually rename it to match your executable's name and deploy it along with the application

Comment: Have you checked the link posted by musium? That shows how configuration works in .NET Core. All NuGet packages *depend* on `IConfiguration` and expect their settings to come from there.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6 and no longer uses `app.config` and the related classes.

Remove the obsolete packages and use the new configuration middleware. Settings are read from multiple sources now, with `appsettings.json` just one of the default sources.

The current Microsoft Sqlite driver is [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli). The current version is 6.0.5

Using the Generic Host package you can add Configuration, Logging and DI middleware to your application in a single line.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Dapper;

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();
```

The default configuration sources are described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#configure-console-apps) and include JSON config files, environment variables and command line arguments.

After that you can retrieve configuration settings by their key. Connection strings get their own method :

```
var Configuration = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

var cns = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
using var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=hello.db");

var rows = await connection.QueryAsync("select * from Test");

Console.WriteLine($"Rows {rows.Count()}");
```

The application's settings are stored in the `appsettings.json` file :

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Default": "./mydb.db"
    }
}
```

Finally, the `csproj` file adds Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` which in turn adds Configuration, Logging and Dependency Injection as dependencies :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You can use only the Configuration middleware if you want, and add only the sources you need :

```
IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
```

Comment: Perfect! This should be marked as answer!